# class "Document" not contained in mongodb jar

Tags: java, mongodb, jar, libraries

I downloaded a mongoldb driver for java from this link:

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver/3.4.2/

In my Netbeans Java Web Application I right-clicked on the Libraries Folder and clicked on "Add JAR/Folder". I navigated to the folder containing the jar-file and added the jar to the Libraries Folder.

According to the documentation, which you can find here:

http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/driver/tutorials/databases-collections/

- in order to get or create a collection one has to write the following line of code:

  MongoCollection coll = database.getCollection("NameOfCollection");

The problem is that the Document class is not recognized by the IDE.

I therefore checked the jar-file I downloaded. The Document class is supposed to be in the org.bson package.

However, as you can see from the screenshot, there is no Dokument class in that package:

[image]

I don't know what to do now. Without that class I can't even access the mongodb database.

Where do I get that class from?

************************UPDATE*******************************

Here's a screenshot of my Libraries folder showing that the jar-file included is for version 3.4 of the java driver:

[image]

Comment: At a glance it's missing quite a lot of classes and in fact I would warrant this is actually a v2 driver, [since the class list matches that specification](http://api.mongodb.com/java/2.13/org/bson/package-frame.html). Check your dependencies since you seem to have the wrong jar here.

Comment: In fact when you look at http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/javadoc/ I see `gridFs` directly above `util` here and that again only matches the v2 driver, the v3 driver would have `com.mongodb.selector` directly before `util`.

Comment: So I got java-driver/2 instead of java-driver/3.4 ?  But the link above says it's version 3.4 ... where is version 3.4 if not under that link?

Comment: The class list disagrees. Check your dependency management, as you clearly have the wrong jar installed.

Comment: @Neil: I provided another screenshot (see above) ... the jar file indicates that it's version 3.4

Comment: Are you using maven or grade? I am using maven and Mongo on a project. No problems at all

Comment: I am not using maven .... (I wanted to but there was some weird problem with existing code (I have overtaken a haf-fiished project) so in the end I didn't use maven)

Comment: try grade then. they make life a lot easier

Comment: It does not matter what the file name is, it is simply not the correct JAR. Listen to what everyone is telling you and use a proper dependency manager to actually resolve the libraries.

Comment: what I did now is to download version 3.4.1 instead of 3.4.2 .... now it works

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: it is easier to manually install a jar into maven/gradle work around some problems than to cherry pick over the internet junk